# Slideshow using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, slideshow, onload

I am new in javascript, so here is my question. I am making a slideshow of three images using html css and javaScript. But it starts always with the second image.

Here my code:

```
var slideIndex=0;
window.onload=showSlides;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you have incorrect usage of function. you use it twice:

```
window.onload=showSlides;
showSlides();
```

instead, use one of them.

2) whenever function is executed, it may jump to second image. If so, simply start from `-1` start index, instead of `0`.